Dockerfile with pnpm running on Google Cloud Build failing
I'm trying to create a docker container that has pnpm and gcloud cli installed, so that I can run a number of build steps on Google Cloud Build. Each step is split so that I can track if one step is increasing in time.
The steps should include installing dependencies, installing any global cli packages that will be used in the build steps, and then calling multiple package.json scripts to run build and deploy commands.
Here is my current Dockerfile
FROM node:20.11.1

# Explicitly set the shell to bash
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"

# Install pnpm
RUN corepack enable pnpm

# Setup pnpm
RUN pnpm setup

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]

and my cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
  - id: ':package: Installing dependencies with pnpm'
    name: 'charliefrancis/pnpm:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    dir: '/workspace'
    args: ['-c', 'pnpm install --frozen-lockfile']

  - id: ':earth_africa: Adding global packages'
    name: 'charliefrancis/pnpm:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    dir: '/workspace'
    args: ['-c', 'pnpm add --global firebase-tools@latest @sentry/cli@latest']

Step 0 completes, but Step 1 fails with this error
Already have image (with digest): charliefrancis/pnpm:latest
 ERR_PNPM_NO_GLOBAL_BIN_DIR  Unable to find the global bin directory

Run "pnpm setup" to create it automatically, or set the global-bin-dir setting, or the PNPM_HOME env variable. The global bin directory should be in the PATH.

I don't seem to be able to access pnpm after the first step.

The issue was caused by running pnpm setup in both the Dockerfile and the first Cloud Build step. This created separate global configurations that conflicted.
